# Management automation host rectangle: bottom cannot be greater than or equal to top

Tags: c#, powershell, pshost

I'm getting an error saying bottom cannot be greater than or equal to top.

I'm using the `Rectangle` constructor documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.rectangle.-ctor?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Host_Rectangle__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_

This is my relevant section of code;

```
            Console.WriteLine("setting rectangles: " + sizex +", " +sizey);
            int screenTop = sizey;
            int screenBottom = 1;
            int statusTop = 1;
            int statusBottom = 0;
            Console.WriteLine ("screen top bottom; "+screenTop + " > " + screenBottom );
            Console.WriteLine ("status top bottom; "+statusTop + " > " + statusBottom );
            
         // Rectangle(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
            System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle screenWindowRect = new Rectangle(0,screenTop,sizex,screenBottom);
            System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle statusLineRect = new Rectangle(0,statusTop,sizex,statusBottom);
            Console.WriteLine("rectangles set");
```

I see the debug lines before the constructors, but never the "rectangles set" message.

This is the output;

```
setting rectangles: 241, 28
screen top bottom; 28 > 1
status top bottom; 1 > 0
Out-Less: "bottom" cannot be greater than or equal to "top".
```

I can see that top is greater than bottom but I keep getting the error; `"bottom" cannot be greater than or equal to "top"`

Is this a bug, or documentation error, or is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error message *misstates* the actual error condition**:

> `"bottom" cannot be greater than or equal to "top"`

should be:

> `"bottom" cannot be less than "top"`

In other words: **the `bottom` argument must be *equal to or greater than* the `top` argument** - and, analogously, **`right` must be *equal to or greater than* `left`**:

You can verify this in PowerShell itself:

```sh
# OK: 1 -ge 1
# Arguments are: left, top, right, bottom
[System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle]::new(0, 1, 0, 1)

# OK: 2 -ge 1
[System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle]::new(0, 1, 0, 2)

# !! EXCEPTION: 0 -ge 1 is NOT true.
[System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle]::new(0, 1, 0, 0)
```